# WIF return to the RP application

Tags: c#, wif

I am building a WIF STS and I am able to generate a token. How do I return the token back to the orignal URL. I've noticed this is present in the wctx parameter in the form ru=. How do i extract this without manually parsing this as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return the token back to the relying party, you can just use the [ProcessRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee733644.aspx) method similar to this:

```
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(WSIdentityConstants.ClaimTypes.Name, User.Identity.Name),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.AuthenticationMethod, FormsAuthenticationHelper.GetAuthenticationMethod(User.Identity))
    };

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, STS.TokenServiceIssueTypes.Native);
        var principal = ClaimsPrincipal.CreateFromIdentity(identity);

        FederatedPassiveSecurityTokenServiceOperations.ProcessRequest(
            Request,
            principal,
            StarterTokenServiceConfiguration.Current.CreateSecurityTokenService(),
            Response);
```

If you're just looking to extract the URL parameters, take a look at [WSFederationMessage.CreateFromUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.protocols.wsfederation.wsfederationmessage.createfromuri.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm already doing pretty much the same. But we need to override the GetScope method and assign a ReplyTo parameter. This is where I'm a little confused. How do I extract the values from the context variable? Since I want to hit the RP endpoint with the newly created token.

Comment: You can override `GetScope` in your `SecurityTokenService`-derived class.  If you want to change the ReplyTo, just use something like this:     

`protected override Scope  GetScope(
       Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.IClaimsPrincipal principal, 
        RequestSecurityToken request)
    {

        Scope scope = new Scope(request);
        scope.ReplyToAddress = yourAddress;
        return scope;
    }`

Comment: Look here for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347547.aspx#id0100026

Comment: Thanks was able to resolve this. I was trying to manually parse the AppliesTo URL into the Reply parameter, instead of setting it on the config.